# virtualenv & subprocess: How to get the correct path to a script

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenv, circusd

When someone installs my Python package, they can use the command `mycmd` (it's a console script added to the python `bin/` directory). In turn, `mycmd` launches several other Python console scripts using `subprocess`:

`subprocess.Process('celery arg1 arg2')
subprocess.Process('huey arg1 arg2')
...`

(`celery` and `huey` commands are installed through my package's pip dependencies.)

This generally works fine, except in the situation where someone invokes `mycmd` directly without activating its virtualenv. For example, I am trying to use `mycmd` inside the process control system "circusd". See [here](https://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/step-by-step/) where the `circus.ini` file invokes `venv/bin/chaussette` directly, without actually activating the `venv`. If I do this, I get the message `celery: No such file or directory`, I presume because the virtualenv is not activated and therefore those commands are not found on the path.

**How can I ensure that when someone runs `mycmd`, the correct `celery` gets run, even if the virtualenv was not activated?** (And should also work if the person is not using virtualenv at all, and cross-platform, etc.)

By the way, I am not using `subprocess.Process` directly, but rather using [Honcho](https://honcho.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#honcho.manager.Manager.add_process), which provides a layer around it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this simply by adding my virtualenv `bin` path to the `PATH` used by `circus`.